# Why does the charge redistribute among the metallic balls connected to current carrying wires?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current, capacitance

[image]

In the above circuit,as soon as the switch is closed,current flows in the circuit,maintaining constant potential differences between each resitors(V/2) at steady state,causing constant potential difference between the metallic spheres,while calculating the charges on each sphere(assuming they are far away,for three variables(charge on each spheres),we require 3 constraints to find unique solution ,two of the constraints are potential differences between each pair of sphere,while the third constraint as while solving the problem is taken as summation of net charge on spheres must be zero,

I can't understand why is the third constraint applicable,as the extra charge may flow in the circuit through current,as there is electric field inside wire?

Comment: Is this a homework problem? I'm guessing that the third constraint is arbitrary--imposed by your prof. The third constraint ensures that there will be only one solution, but there is no physical reason why the whole circuit could not hold an extra charge.

Comment: @SolomonSlow,I can think of another example where charge conservation is used,lets say we have uncharged capacitor connected parallel to resistor and battery is attached,when switch is closed,after some time steady state is reached,while current is still flowing through resistor,so why do we say that left end of plate must have equal charge in magnitude that of right plate,why can't take some extra charge from one plate and give less charge to another plate,while still maintaining constant potential difference?

Answer (score 1):

Those three spheres can be thought of as two capacitors one in parallel with the resistor between nodes $A$ and $B$ and the other in parallel with the resistor between nodes $B$ and $C$.

If the whole circuit is electrically isolated then the net charge contained within the whole circuit cannot change.
Thus if there was no net charge on the capacitors before the switch was closed that condition would be the same after the switch was closed although there would be a redistribution of charge on each of the capacitor.
There will be a positive charge on the sphere connected to node $A$ with an equal magnitude negative charge on the sphere connected to node $C$.
The central sphere would have a zero net charge but with  negative charge on the left and equal magnitude positive charge on the right.

Comment: I understand that net charge initially was zero,so in circuit,net charge final must be zero,But why can't some extra charge flow in circuit and less charge be accumulated on spheres,as there is electric field inside,it is possible to flow extra charge to flow, while maintaining net neutrality of circuit?

Comment: As with a capacitor the charge on each "plate" is equal in magnitude and opposite in sign.